# False clang error when calling a template template method with a template that is in a namespace

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, clang++

I have a template template method which works fine when calling it with a template that is not in a namespace. However, I get a clang error when calling it with a template that is in a namespace. MSVC and gcc compile without problems, but only when I set the standard to C++17.

Here is a minimal example

```
#include <vector>

template<template<typename> typename Template>
Template<int> foo() {
    return {};
}

template <typename T>
using my_vector = std::vector<T>;

int main()
{
    foo<my_vector>(); // compiles
    foo<std::vector>(); // does not compile in clang or without C++17
}
```

[Here is a live example.](https://godbolt.org/g/C21EiP)

The gcc error without C++17 is:

```
<source>:14:5: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
```

The clang error is:

```
<source>:14:22: error: no matching function for call to 'foo<template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector>()'
<source>:4:15: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'Template'
```

What changed in C++17 to allow this, and is it a bug that clang produces an error?

Comment: IMHO, naming a template type parameter `Template` is a debatable choice :)

Comment: [P0522R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0522r0.html). See https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#p0522 for the reason why clang disables this feature.

Comment: @lubgr Yes yes, I know, I just thought in this example it might make clear what I mean :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vector is

```
template<class T, class Allocator=std::allocator<T>>
class vector;
```

note it takes 2 parameters.

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) templates that take 2 parameters can match `template<class>class` if the 2nd one is defaulted; in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) this was not true.

As for clang in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), they [found a bug in the standard](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#p0522) if you implement this feature: (via @cpplearner in comments above)

> (10): Despite being the resolution to a Defect Report, this feature is disabled by default in all language versions, and can be enabled explicitly with the flag -frelaxed-template-template-args in Clang 4 onwards. The change to the standard lacks a corresponding change for template partial ordering, resulting in ambiguity errors for reasonable and previously-valid code. This issue is expected to be rectified soon.

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) this may work:

```
template<template<class...> class Z>
Z<int> foo() {
  return {};
}
```

as there are rules letting `class...` match any number of arguments.

Comment: Damn, I forgot that the std container classes have more template parameters. You're right. This works:

    template<template<typename...> typename Template>
    Template<int> foo() {
        return {};
    }

Comment: Another option is to use the flag -frelaxed-template-template-args, but that of course might lead to errors in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> What changed in C++17 to allow this, and is it a bug that clang produces an error?

Yes the behavior changed since C++17, and Clang seems not conformance to the standard.

Note that [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) has 2 template parameters (the 2nd one has default value), while the template template parameter `Template` expects only one. They don't match.

Since C++17 ([CWG 150](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#150)), the default template arguments are allowed for a [template template argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_arguments) to match a template template parameter with fewer template parameters.

> ```
> template<class T> class A { /* ... */ };
> template<class T, class U = T> class B { /* ... */ };
>
> template<template<class> class P> class X { /* ... */ };
> X<A> xa; // OK
> X<B> xb; // OK in C++17 after CWG 150
>          // Error earlier: not an exact match
> ```